Auto-py-to-exe cannot find base_library.zip?
I'm trying to convert a .py into an .exe.
Until now this tools auto-py-to-exe has always worked.
Today I've got this error:
21080 ERROR: base_library.zip could not be created!
An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\auto-py-to-exe-master\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 135, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 212, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 69, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1186, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1126, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu1pbmgcj\Download_Remoto_File .spec", line 4, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
        ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 527, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 623, in assemble
    create_py3_base_library(libzip_filename, graph=self.graph)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\utils.py", line 59, in create_py3_base_library
    with zipfile.ZipFile(libzip_filename, mode='w') as zf:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\zipfile\__init__.py", line 1331, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpu1pbmgcj\\build\\File \\base_library.zip'

any idea of what base_library.zip is? and how to fix this error?
I tried also with pyinstaller placing the .py in the same folder of pyinstaller and sending the command:
pyinstaller --onefile File.py

seems that the error is the same of auto-py-to-exe
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Scripts>pyinstaller --onefile "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Scripts\File.py"
296 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.6.0, contrib hooks: 2024.6
297 INFO: Python: 3.12.3
332 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
333 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Scripts\File.spec
342 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312-32\\Scripts']
578 INFO: checking Analysis
579 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
580 INFO: Running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
580 INFO: Target bytecode optimization level: 0
581 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
582 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
598 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1718 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4024 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5174 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5634 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
5679 ERROR: base_library.zip could not be created!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 228, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 212, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 69, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1186, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1126, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Scripts\File.spec", line 4, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
        ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 527, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 623, in assemble
    create_py3_base_library(libzip_filename, graph=self.graph)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\utils.py", line 59, in create_py3_base_library
    with zipfile.ZipFile(libzip_filename, mode='w') as zf:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\zipfile\__init__.py", line 1331, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312-32\\Scripts\\build\\File\\base_library.zip'


The space after File looks suspicious; how did that get in there?

uhm what space?forgive me but I don't see it...ah I see it you mena "\File \base_library.zip'".... I have no idea... it is all made by the tool, I think...

"Errno 2" just means file-not-found. That's a lot less specific than saying it can't find a specific file (in this case base-library.zip), so I've edited the title accordingly.

honestly I'ven't found a solution that fix this problem but I've moved in a new folder a backup of the file which I was trying to convert into .exe and using auto-py-to-exe this time it worked....to me, but this is only my personal opinion which has no confirmation, it stucked in some windows register/library?
